# How can I reuse the function of the inheritance method as if I hadn't used it before?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

After running 'new object.data comparison' function, I want to filter with a new list. and giving a new list to data_comparison method.new_object.data takes the value of the list I filtered last. but how can I reuse it as if I hadn't used data_comparison before? very very very thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import os


csv_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/dataset/traffic-crashes-vehicles-1.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
class MainData:
    def __init__(self, filter_items=None):
        self.data = data
        self.filter_items = filter_items

    def column_filter(self):
        self.data = self.data[self.filter_items]
        return self.data

    def data_clean(self):
        self.data = self.data.dropna()
        return self.data

    def data_comparison(self,item_compare_lists):
        item_compare_list = item_compare_lists
   
        for i in item_compare_list:
            if i == 'less than and equal to':
                self.data = self.data[self.data[item_compare_list[i]['item']].le(item_compare_list[i]['value'])]
            elif i == 'less than and not equal to value':
                self.data = self.data[self.data[item_compare_list[i]['item']].lt(item_compare_list[i]['value'])]
            elif i == 'the greater and not equal':
                self.data = self.data[self.data[item_compare_list[i]['item']].gt(item_compare_list[i]['value'])]
            elif i == 'greater and equal':
                self.data = self.data[self.data[item_compare_list[i]['item']].ge(item_compare_list[i]['value'])]
            elif i == 'equal to':
                self.data = self.data[self.data[item_compare_list[i]['item']].eq(item_compare_list[i]['value'])]
            elif i == 'not equal':
                self.data = self.data[self.data[item_compare_list[i]['item']].ne(item_compare_list[i]['value'])]
            else:
                print('eşit değil')
        return self.data



new_object = MainData(filter_items=['MAKE', 'NUM_PASSENGERS', 'VEHICLE_YEAR'])



new_object.column_filter()
```

#new_object.column_filter() output

```
                          MAKE  NUM_PASSENGERS  VEHICLE_YEAR
6                CHEVROLET             NaN        2017.0
7                   NISSAN             NaN        2017.0
18                 HYUNDAI             1.0        2017.0
24                   DODGE             NaN        2017.0
47               CHEVROLET             NaN        2017.0
```

#after filtering date data in column. first filter

```
item_compare_list = {
    'less than and not equal to value': {'item': 'VEHICLE_YEAR', 'value': 2018},
    'the greater and not equal': {'item': 'VEHICLE_YEAR', 'value': 2016},
}


new_object.data_comparison(item_compare_lists=item_compare_list)
print(new_object.data)
```

#the part i have a problem with. second filter list

```
item_compare = {
    'less than and not equal to value': {'item': 'VEHICLE_YEAR', 'value': 2019},
    'the greater and not equal': {'item': 'VEHICLE_YEAR', 'value': 2017},
}


new_object.data_comparison(item_compare_lists=item_compare)

print(new_object.data)
```

## the problem i had after the second filter and output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [MAKE, NUM_PASSENGERS, VEHICLE_YEAR]
Index: []
```

I know the cause of the problem Changed the data when the first data_comparison function ran. When I wanted to use it for the second time, data came back to 'data_comparison' not in its original form but in its filtered form. What I want is that every time I use the data_comparison method again, the first data, not the data_comparison data, remains.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Moreover, what is `self.data = self.data[self.filter_items]` supposed to do, knowing that `self.filter_items` is a list?

Comment: You are quite right, I made more points and additions to explain the question better. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is based on the fact, that the method is not a *pure* function. (You might want to familiarize yourself with the concept.) Instead it is *impure*, i.e. it changes the state of the object.

To make it pure, do not make it apply changes to the object, but let it simply return the value. There are different styles how to deal with methods in object oriented programming: Some designs prefer objects to be totally immutable; other designs allow mutation of the object. But in general, *both* manipulating the object *and* returning a value in one method, is a bad idea.

So, in the `data_comparison` method, you could write, in the beginning of the method:

```py
data = self.data
```

and then replace all following usages of `self.data` by `data` in that method. This will keep `self.data` unchanged, and hence does not change the state of the object. (Remember that the first parameter in every method, `self`, is referring to the object. So changing the attribute `data` of `self` is changing the object.)

There are other flaws in your code as well, but since this is not a code review, I will confine myself to answer your specific question.

Comment: I try immediately and I will return. thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work harder to correct my shortcomings. thank you very much for your help